# wrong URL triggers an infinite redirect loop in Hapijs

Tags: hapi.js

I have the following setup with Hapijs 18.4.x (showing only the relevant code below)

```js
// ./index.js
await server.register(
    { plugin: require('./api/v2/index.js'), options: {} },
    { routes: { prefix: '/v2' } }
);


// ./api/v2/index.js
exports.plugin = {
    register: async function(server, options) {

        await server.register([
            { plugin: require('./resources/resource1') },
            { plugin: require('./resources/resource2') },
            { plugin: require('./resources/resource3') }

            // and so on
        ]);

    }
};


// ./api/v2/resources/resource1.js 
// (similar code in other resource{\d}.js files)

module.exports = return {
    plugin: {
        name: resource1,
        register: function(server, options) {

            server.route([{ 
                path: '/resource1',   
                method: 'GET', 
                handler: handler
            }]);
        },
    },
}
```

all is good as long as the requested path is correct. If the requested path is incorrect, then the application goes into an infinite loop appending `/v2` to the URI till it crashes. For example, if the request is for `http://server/v2/resrouce1?param1=foo&param2=bar` (typo `resrouce1` instead of `resource1`), the browser shows the following in the URL bar, and the server crashes with **Internal Server Error: Parse Error**

```
http://server/v2/v2/v2/v2/v2/v2… ad infinitum till crash… /v2/resrouce1?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this so if someone types a wrong path, a proper 404 is returned, not an infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: Do you do anything particular in the routes handlers ?

Comment: Of course, I do a lot of things in the route handlers, but I am assuming you want to know if I do anything to the `path` in the route handlers. No. The code never reaches the handler, as far as I can tell. My guess is that the router (wherever that is, in `hapijs`) prefixes the (wrong) resource with `/v2`, tries to find the resource, doesn't find it, prefixes `/v2` again, and the process goes on

Answer (score 0):

figured out the error. I had an old bit of errant code that tried to *helpfully* add the api version prefix in case no specific version was provided by the user. The code was buggy, so when it didn't find a resource, its logic thought that the api version was missing. So it added the prefix with the *hope* of redirecting to the resource, and that set off the loop. I took out the errant code because, on second thought, second-guessing what the user is trying to request is just not a good pattern for an API.